# AdMob ad is received but it won't display

Tags: android, admob

I'm adding AdMob ads to my app. The test ad works fine in the emulator, but when I test it on a phone it doesn't display. Looking at LogCat, it says it received the ad, and it doesn't say that the space allotted is too small to hold the ad (I checked and it would tell me if that happened), but the test ad does not appear. I can't find any reason that the test ad would be successfully received and have enough space yet not be displayed, so I'm fairly stumped.

Comment: How are you setting test mode?  `AdRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR)` only sets the emulator for test mode.  If you want to whitelist a device for test mode, you will need to call `AdRequest.addTestDevice("YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID");`  This can be found in the logcat output when making a request on a device not already whitelisted for test mode.

Answer (score 1):

AdMob doesn't always show an AD. 
The number of ads shown depend on how many requests you application make.

Few requests = few probability to see the banner.

Then if you doesn't receive any error and your logcat says that the ad is received correctly, then probably it is ok.

On my application installed on ~2000 devices the AD appears very rarely.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the test ad should be shown 100% of the time; I think that's the point.

Comment: yeah the test probably yes. But i read somewhere on the site that the ADS when not in test, will be not always be shown. It depends on the amount of your requests.